# Sending PATCH request using WebClient in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, webclient

I have an older ASP.NET WebForms site. I am trying to use `WebClient` to send a `PATCH` request to a REST API:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer " + authToken;
    try
    {
        responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadValues(endpoint, "PATCH", body));
    }                
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return e;
    }            
}
```

In this snippet, `endpoint` is the URI I'm `PATCH`-ing to, and `body` is a `NameValueCollection`.

This gives me an HTTP 400 "Bad Request" error. If I drill down in the exception, it indicates a protocol violation. I have tried adding a header for content-type, but that did not help.

This same code **does** work for `POST` requests, and it's how I'm getting my access token successfully. But it does not work for `PATCH`. Is there any way to send a valid `PATCH` request using `WebClient`?

I realize there are other libraries out there, but if possible, I'd like to be consistent with the rest of the code in this class in using `WebClient`. If I have to switch to something else, I'd want to update the rest of the code too.

**Update**

Yes, the API does support `PATCH`. It's the Microsoft Graph API and PATCH works fine with Postman.

Comment: Does your API support PATCH?

Comment: Yes, it's Microsoft Graph API and PATCH works fine with Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using the `UploadString` method, as follows:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer " + authToken;
    try
    {
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
        responseString = client.UploadString(endpoint, method, body);
    }                
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return e;
    }            
}
```

Where `body` is a JSON-formatted string, instead of a `NameValueCollection` as I was trying initially. I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this, but it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks ok. If the API supports PATCH you should receive a response.
Could you check if PATCH is implemented on the API?

Another possibility is that you violate some validation rules applied in PATCH method.

Comment: Yes, it's Microsoft Graph API and PATCH works fine with Postman.